# How to get back from modal to main view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm totally newbie level with swift and having a question. so, I created a navigation controller for my modal and having my modal opened up from my first view controller with segue (Button2). The question is, how to get back to my first view controller from Modal View

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) method to dismiss a specific ViewController.

The question is how you want to dismiss the ViewController presented modally? With a button? Tap anywhere in the View? Tap on a little cross button?

For example if you have an UIButton to dismiss:

```
@IBAction func didTapClose(_ sender: UIButton) {
      dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the segue is **"present modally"**, you can dismiss the view controller through this line :

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Else If the segue is **"show"**, you can dismiss the view controller through this line :

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
```

> In this case, be sure that you embedded your ViewController to a navigationController in your storyboard. If your ViewController is not embedded to a navigationController and you have used **show** segue, you should use `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` to return to previous page.

Also there is other ways to return to previous pages (e.g., [unwind segue](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f))

Good luck.